# Is it possible to alter a web application view to suit a tablets orientation

Tags: ipad, html, cross-platform, css

I am working on a web application using HTML5 CSS3 and Javascript so that its compatible with Tablets. I have included basic touch specific events that webkit offers. I would like to know if it is possible to change the layout or the design of a web app based on the orientation of the tablet.

What I have noticed is that web app does not fully utilize the space on the tablet(IPad) and the layout appears odd. Is there any way I can modify the design and layout based on the orientation.

Will appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there no need to write window.onresize you can did it simply with CSS.You have write in html page

```
<meta name="viewport" content = "user-scalable=no, width=1024" />'
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="stylesheet/ipad.css" type="text/css" />;
```

& write your css for ipad.For more information must saw these link's http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ipad-layout-with-landscape-portrait-modes , http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/toolbox/article.php/3889591/Detect-and-Set-the-iPhone--iPads-Viewport-Orientation-Using-JavaScript-CSS-and-Meta-Tags.htm , http://thomasmaier.me/blog/2010/03/04/howto-css-for-the-ipad/

Comment: Thank you. The articles were of great help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a tablet expert, but it looks like you could alter your layout based on `window.onresize`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this excellent article about [Responsive Web Design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/) from [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/).

You can include stylesheets for only certain screen-resolutions by using media queries like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
  media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)"
  href="shetland.css" />
```

and you can even use a media query right in your CSS like this:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  .column {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

Then you can set up a single page with a layout that automatically adjusts to the available width.

---

I tried this with my own site; for `@media screen and (max-width: 600px)` I switch from a two-column layout to one. It works when I resize the window in Chrome, but on my Droid Incredible I still get two columns. I didn't have time to look into whether I should be using `max-device-width` or if perhaps the Android browser doesn't support this feature. If it's the latter, I'm sure Apple is enough with the times that this should work for you, though.

Good luck!